# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty 0

Tags: flutter

Recently I have been trying to do a search bar for my flutter application, however, the search bar able to detect the first letter of the word entered in the search bar but once I enter the 2nd letter of the search, the error `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty 0` pops out. I have checked a few solutions and they said to implement `itemCount` but I am using the `AlphabetScrollView` instead of `ListView`.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:alphabet_scroll_view/alphabet_scroll_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_grocery/databaseManager/DatabaseManager.dart';

import 'AddItem.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late User user;
  User? currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();

  bool isLoggedin = true;
  bool _isEdit = false;

  List groceryItemList = [];
  List nameList = [];
  List itemsIdList = [];
  List items = [];

  late List groceries;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchGroceryItemList();
    fetchItemId();
  }

  fetchGroceryItemList() async {
    dynamic resultant = await DatabaseManager().getGroceryList(currentUser);
    if (resultant == null) {
      print("Unable to retrieve");
    } else {
      setState(() {
        groceryItemList = resultant;
        groceryItemList.forEach((e) => nameList.add(e["itemName"]));
        items.addAll(groceryItemList);
        print("NAMELIST: $nameList");
        print("ITEMS: $items");
      });
    }
  }

  fetchItemId() async {
    Query itemId = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Items')
        .doc(currentUser!.uid)
        .collection('Item')
        .orderBy("itemName");

    await itemId.get().then((docs) {
      setState(() {
        docs.docs.forEach((doc) => {itemsIdList.add(doc.id)});
      });
    });
  }

  getUser() async {
    User? firebaseUser = _auth.currentUser;
    await firebaseUser!.reload();
    firebaseUser = _auth.currentUser!;

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      setState(() {
        this.user = firebaseUser!;
        this.isLoggedin = true;
      });
    }
  }

  void filterSearchResults(String query) {
    final searchLower = query.toLowerCase();
    List<dynamic> dummyData = [];
    dummyData.addAll(items);

    if (searchLower.isNotEmpty) {
      List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> dummySearchResult = [];
      dummyData.forEach((item) {
        if (item["itemName"].contains(searchLower)) {
          dummySearchResult.add(item);
          print("DUMMY DATA: ${dummySearchResult}");
        }
      });

      setState(() {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(dummySearchResult);
        print("ITEMS DATA: ${items}");
      });

      return;
    } else {
      print("FALSE");
      setState(() {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(groceryItemList);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 65.0,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff2C6846),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: const Text('Home'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded),
            tooltip: 'Open User Profile',
            iconSize: 40,
            onPressed: () {
              // handle the press
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(children: [
        Container(
          width: 350.0,
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 0),
          child: TextField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              filterSearchResults(value);
              // searchGroceries;
            },
            controller: searchController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                  onPressed: () {
                    searchController.clear();
                  },
                ),
                hintText: 'Search...',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                )),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: AlphabetScrollView(
          list: nameList.map((e) => AlphaModel(e)).toList(),
          alignment: LetterAlignment.right,
          itemExtent: 150,
          unselectedTextStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, color: Colors.black),
          selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Color(0xff2C6846)),
          overlayWidget: (value) => Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.star,
                size: 50,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  '$value'.toUpperCase(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          itemBuilder: (_, index, buildContext) {
            return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          AddItem(!_isEdit, itemsIdList[index])));
                },
                child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.0, 30, 0.0),
                    height: 90,
                    child: ListTile(
                      shape: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 199, 199, 199),
                              width: 1)),
                      title: Text(items.length > 0
                          ? "${items[index]["itemName"]}"
                          : ""),
                      subtitle: Text(items.length > 0
                          ? "${items[index]["price"]}/${items[index]["measurementMatrix"]}"
                          : ""),
                      leading: (Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(items[index]["itemImage"]))),
                      trailing: Text(items.length > 0
                          ? "Stock Amount: ${items[index]["stockAmount"]}"
                          : ""),
                    )));
          },
        ))
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Another error occurs is also `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1:2`. I am new to flutter and sorry if the nested is too much, will try to improve in future.

Answer (score 0):

First try initializing **textEditingController** on initstate() and dispose it like:

```
late TextEditingController searchController;
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    searchController = TextEditingController();
}

@override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    searchController.dispose();
 }
```

Try this first and let's see what happens.

Comment: The error still exist after i added dispose, but may I know what does dispose do?

Comment: This is from api.flutter.dev, "Remember to dispose of the TextEditingController when it is no longer needed. This will ensure we discard any resources used by the object".

Comment: Now, when you try to print the items in console, are they present there. If so, then check if it is due to dealy because of async nature of operation since you're getting "itemsIdList" from a "fetchItemId" function which is asynchronous.

Comment: I think the error is due to the fact that the listview supposedly to have for example a list of 6 items but if i filter it through the search function, then it will become 3, which another 3 is empty

Comment: If so then you can use something similar to:  items != null ?  Your Widget : null

Comment: tried but still error, i think at this moment i will just stop using the alphabet scroll view and start using the listview.builder then